# how to add flag on spark dataframe based on transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

i have a spark dataframe all the values are string type

```
Vehicle Production Model  ECU         As-Is   modelData     Coding  Flag
22223   22233        C24      BR-11   A42222  A2223          A3442   0
22223   22233        C24      BR-11   A3442   A2223          A3442   0
22223   22233        C24      BR-11   A3443   A2223          A3443   1
22223   22233        C24      BR-12   A3442   A2223          A3443   1
22224   22234        C24      BR-12   A3442   A2223          A3443   1
22224   22234        C24      BR-13   A3443   A2223          A3446   0
22224   22234        C24      BR-13   A3447   A2223          A3444   0
22224   22234        C24      BR-13   A3448   A2225          A3443   0
```

it should loop through each unique vehicle
under each unique vehicle, it should loop through  each unique ECU
under each ECu it should pick a unique AS-IS list
and (combination of unique modelData and coding where Flag=0 ignoring null values)

then it should compare the AS-IS list with (combination of unique modelData and coding where Flag=0)
for each element in AS-IS is found in (combination of unique modelData and coding where Flag=0) list then mark
As_Is_Flag column as 1 else 0

this should go on for all unique vehicles

expected output:

```
Vehicle Production Model  ECU     As-Is      modelData     Coding  Flag  As-Is Flag
22223   22233        C24      BR-11  A42222  A2223         A3442    0       0
22223   22233        C24      BR-11  A3442    A2223        A3442    0       1
22223   22233        C24      BR-11  A3443    A2223        A3443    1       0
22223   22233        C24      BR-12   A3442   A2223        A3443    1       1
22224   22234        C24      BR-12   A3442   A2223        A3443    1       0
22224   22234        C24      BR-13   A3443   A2223        A3446    0       1
22224   22234        C24      BR-13   A3447   A2223        A3444    0       0
22224   22234        C24      BR-13   A3448   A2225        A3443    0       0
```

using pyspark

tried a couple of things but couldn't work

Comment: Make it more clear

Comment: "but couldn't work" - please describe what exactly didn't work as supposed, what was the result or an error

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you tried, and post it here ?